# pytesseract ошибка чтения просто изображения

Tags: python, opencv

Я пытаюсь получить текст из простого изображения на MacOS:

```
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/opt/homebrew/bin/pytesseract"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')
```

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, ак можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Что выведет print(img)

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
result_text=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'), lang='rus')
```

то есть ты просто не указал язык

Comment: Язык же там опциональный параметр по идеи - такой код тоже не работает с той же ошибкой

Comment: whereis tesseract-ocr, выводит верный путь? и вообще tesseract-ocr установлен? из консоли пайтессеракт работает?